# Partial derivative of e

Tags: proof-verification, partial-derivative

Lets say I want to do partial derivative in respect to $w$:

$$
\frac{\partial e^{w^T\phi(x^i)}}{\partial w}
$$

Where $w$ is a vector and $\phi(x^i)$ is a also a vector.

Can I treat $\phi(x^i)$ like a scalar, so that, the derivative will be:

$$
\frac{\partial e^{w^T\phi(x^i)}}{\partial w} = \phi(x^i)e^{w^T\phi(x^i)}
$$

?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, it seems that both $w$ and $\phi$ are vectors, the good thing is that you can write this in components

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}e^{w^T\phi(x^i)} &=& e^{w^T\phi(x^i)}\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k} (w^T\phi(x^i)) \\
&=& e^{w^T\phi(x^i)}\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k} \left(\sum_jw_j\phi_j(x^i)\right) \\
&=& e^{w^T\phi(x^i)} \phi_k(x^i) \\
&=& (\phi(x^i))_k e^{w^T\phi(x^i)}  \\
&=& \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial w}e^{w^T\phi(x^i)} \right)_k
\end{eqnarray}

In vector form

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w}e^{w^T\phi(x^i)}  = \phi(x^i) e^{w^T\phi(x^i)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule, you certainly have

$$\frac{\partial e^{w^T\phi}}{\partial w}=\frac{\partial({w^T\phi})}{\partial w}e^{w^T\phi}$$

and if your operator denotes the gradient, it is not difficult to show

$$\frac{\partial({w^T\phi})}{\partial w}=\phi.$$